# Different Python version between Dataproc master and worker nodes

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I had created a dataproc cluster with Anaconda as optional component and created a virtual env. in that. Now when running a pyspark py file on master node I'm getting this error -

> Exception: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in
>   driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please
>   check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON
>   are correctly set.

I need RDKit package inside the virtual env. and with that python 3x version gets installed. The following commands on my master node and then the python version changes.

```
conda create -n my-venv -c rdkit rdkit=2019.*   
conda activate my-venv
conda install -c conda-forge rdkit
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things here:

The `1.3` (default) image uses conda with Python 2.7. I recommend switching to `1.4` (`--image-version 1.4`) which uses conda with Python 3.6.

If this library will be needed on the workers you can use [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/python) initialization action to apply the change consistently to all nodes.

Pyspark does not currently support virtualenvs, but this support is coming. Currently you can run pyspark program from within a virtualenv, but this will not mean workers will run inside the virtualenv. Is it possible to apply your changes to the base conda environment without virtualenv?

Additional info can be found here https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration

Comment: Yeah I realized the same and created the cluster using 1.4 image version. And by changing the permissions on /opt/conda/anaconda/ I was able to install the packages  on base env.